# Weird redirect behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I am getting inconsistent behaviors from my Django template on different browsers.

Here is the form:

```html
    <div class="login-form center">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control login-field" value=""
                   placeholder="Enter your Worker-ID here" id="user-id">
            <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="user-id"></label>
        </div>
        <a id="btn-login" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Next</a>
    </div>
```

and the related javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn-login').click(click_event);
    });

    function click_event() {
        let user_id = $('#user-id').val();
        if (!user_id) {
            alert("Please enter your username!")
        }
        else {
            $.post("/snli/api/auth_login/", {
                "username": user_id,
            }, login_callback);
        }
    }

    function login_callback(message) {
        // do more stuff 
        window.location.href = '/snli/human_annotations/'; // <-- the redirect 
    }
```

- On Chrome, it gets redirected to `http://localhost:8000/snli/human_annotations/`
- On Firefox, it gets redirected to `http://localhost:8000/login/?next=/snli/human_annotations/` and then gets stuck on "page not found". This is a problem since my redirect does not work.

Any thoughts what causes this the difference? (and how to resolve it?)

Comment: Some browsers perform the ajax call *after* submitting the form, and thus it is never called.

Comment: How can I verify this hypothesis? (or fix it) Basically, I want consistent behavior across different browsers.

Comment: Can you show the `urls.py` and `views.py` that renders this template?  `login/?next=` is the convention Django uses with their login model, so I'm curious to see if you are using it.